# How make vim's indent line connected(continuos) indent line on iTerm?

Tags: vim, indentation, neovim

I use [indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine) plugin.
And want to make indent line connected(continuos) line.

But it was divided between lines like

```
|
|
|
```

What should I do?

My setting in (neo)vim is

```
let g:indentLine_char = '│'
```

and I use

- NVIM 0.1.7
- iTerm2
- Ricty font

Comment: Probably a font issue and/or the exact UTF-8 pipe you are using. Did you try this character: `┃`? Which font are you using? Does it work with a different font?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing font settings!
 ◯ source code pro
 ✕ ricty